# Efficient implementation for serving 10's of thousands of short lived HTTP requests on a single Linux node?

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel

I'm reading about different approaches for scaling request handling capabilities on a single machine being taken by node.js, ruby, jetty and company.

Being an application developer, i.e. having very little understanding in Kernel/Networking I'm curious to understand the different approaches taken by each implementation (kernel select, polling the socket for connection, event based and company.) ?

Please note that I'm not asking about special handling features (such as [jetty continuations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Continuations) (request->wait->request), a pattern which is typical for AJAX clients) but more generally, should you like to implement a server that can respond with "Hello World" to the maximum number of concurrent clients how would you do it? and Why?

Information / References to reading material would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) page.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this has great background (thanks for reminding me of this paper). The page dates back to 2006/09/02, which is cool because most recent solutions are probably based on the theory provided in the document. I think it would be beneficial to also explain how modern solution (if they divert from the theory and even if not) are implemented. Generally what I'm saying that I would prefer to learn from implemented solution as well as from theory. Again, thanks for the link.

Comment: @Maxim: maybe you should look at libevent and libev.

Comment: !ninjalj: so I assume node.js v8 events [http://nodejs.org/api.html] and ruby eventmachine [http://rubyeventmachine.com/] are both implemented on this concept?